# Group by and sum on multiple keys maintaining type safety

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, grouping

Given an array of objects, I'd like to group it by an arbitrary number of object keys, and sum the values of a second arbitrary number of keys.

For example, given:

```
const arr = [
   { shape: "square", color: "red", available: 1, ordered: 1 },
   { shape: "square", color: "red", available: 2, ordered: 1 },
   { shape: "circle", color: "blue", available: 0, ordered: 3 },
   { shape: "square", color: "blue", available: 4, ordered: 4 },
 ];
```

If I group by both `shape` and `color` and want the sum of the values of `available` and `ordered`, the result should be:

```
[
  { shape: "square", color: "red", available: 3, ordered: 2 },
  { shape: "circle", color: "blue", available: 0, ordered: 3 },
  { shape: "square", color: "blue", available: 4, ordered: 4 },
];
```

I've extensively gone through many similar SO threads [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46794232/8929855), from which the example above is based on, [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29364262/8929855), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19233283/8929855), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49484910/8929855), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69956641/8929855)]. The issue is that none of them:

- Provide a generic, ready-to-use function (they're based on custom object keys)
- Are based on Typescript and provide a type-safe implementation
- Deal adequately with additional keys in the object (e.g., if `arr` contained another property `size` not involved in the transformation it shouldn't contain bogus values)

**How can I build a generic, type-safe `groupBySum` function that accepts multiple grouping and summing keys?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following TypeScript function meets all the desired criteria:

```js
/**
 * Sums object value(s) in an array of objects, grouping by arbitrary object keys.
 *
 * @remarks
 * This method takes and returns an array of objects.
 * The resulting array of object contains a subset of the object keys in the
 * original array.
 *
 * @param arr - The array of objects to group by and sum.
 * @param groupByKeys - An array with the keys to group by.
 * @param sumKeys - An array with the keys to sum. The keys must refer
 *    to numeric values.
 * @returns An array of objects, grouped by groupByKeys and with the values
 *    of keys in sumKeys summed up.
 */
const groupBySum = <T, K extends keyof T, S extends keyof T>(
  arr: T[],
  groupByKeys: K[],
  sumKeys: S[]
): Pick<T, K | S>[] => {
  return [
    ...arr
      .reduce((accu, curr) => {
        const keyArr = groupByKeys.map((key) => curr[key]);
        const key = keyArr.join("-");
        const groupedSum =
          accu.get(key) ||
          Object.assign(
            {},
            Object.fromEntries(groupByKeys.map((key) => [key, curr[key]])),
            Object.fromEntries(sumKeys.map((key) => [key, 0]))
          );
        for (let key of sumKeys) {
          groupedSum[key] += curr[key];
        }
        return accu.set(key, groupedSum);
      }, new Map())
      .values(),
  ];
};
```

The code snippet below uses the JavaScript equivalent to showcase a few examples based on your `arr`:

```js
const arr = [
   { shape: "square", color: "red", available: 1, ordered: 1 },
   { shape: "square", color: "red", available: 2, ordered: 1 },
   { shape: "circle", color: "blue", available: 0, ordered: 3 },
   { shape: "square", color: "blue", available: 4, ordered: 4 },
 ];
 
const groupBySum = (arr, groupByKeys, sumKeys) => {
  return [
    ...arr
      .reduce((accu, curr) => {
        const keyArr = groupByKeys.map((key) => curr[key]);
        const key = keyArr.join("-");
        const groupedSum =
          accu.get(key) ||
          Object.assign(
            {},
            Object.fromEntries(groupByKeys.map((key) => [key, curr[key]])),
            Object.fromEntries(sumKeys.map((key) => [key, 0]))
          );
        for (let key of sumKeys) {
          groupedSum[key] += curr[key];
        }
        return accu.set(key, groupedSum);
      }, new Map())
      .values(),
  ];
};
console.log('groupBySum(arr, ["shape"], ["available"])')
console.log(groupBySum(arr, ["shape"], ["available"]))
console.log('\n\ngroupBySum(arr, ["color"], ["ordered"])')
console.log(groupBySum(arr, ["color"], ["ordered"]))
console.log('\n\ngroupBySum(arr, ["shape", "color"], ["available", "ordered"])')
console.log(groupBySum(arr, ["shape", "color"], ["available", "ordered"]))
```

The Typescript implementation is type-safe. For example, if we try to pass an invalid key...

```
groupBySum(arr, ["blah"], ["ordered"]);
```

... the compiler will complain:

```
Type '"blah"' is not assignable to type '"shape" | "ordered" | "color" | "available"'.ts(2322)
```

The returned object is also type-safe. For example, the type of `ans` in...

```
const ans = groupBySum(arr, ["shape"], ["ordered"])
```

...is:

```
Array<{ shape: string; ordered: number }>;
```

Finally, note that any keys not involved in the transformation are dropped. The example above doesn't contain `color` or `available`, which couldn't possibly contain meaningful values. This is built in the return type, so TypeScript knows not to expect them.

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const arr = [
  { shape: 'square', color: 'red', available: 1, ordered: 1 },
  { shape: 'square', color: 'red', available: 2, ordered: 1 },
  { shape: 'circle', color: 'blue', available: 0, ordered: 3 },
  { shape: 'square', color: 'blue', available: 4, ordered: 4 },
]

function groupAndSum(arr, groupKeys, sumKeys) {
  const groupedData = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const groupValues = groupKeys.map((key) => obj[key]).join('-')

    if (!acc.has(groupValues)) {
      acc.set(groupValues, { ...obj })
    } else {
      const existingObj = acc.get(groupValues)
      sumKeys.forEach((key) => (existingObj[key] += obj[key]))
    }

    return acc
  }, new Map())

  return Array.from(groupedData.values())
}

const groupKeys = ['shape', 'color']
const sumKeys = ['available', 'ordered']

const result = groupAndSum(arr, groupKeys, sumKeys)
console.log(result)
```